# How to stop it at 20?

Tags: c#, sql

```
SELECT movieID, movieTitle, category 
FROM dbo.Movie
ORDER BY movieID DESC
```

How do I get the query to go in descending order by `movieID` but also stop the descend and movieID 20?

Comment: Could you please update the question to make it more understandable? Please add your code, and say what you have tried. Also please reword the question so it goes straight to the point. Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I thought you meant stop at 20 results, but reading your question again, it seems like you want to query until you reach a value of `20` in `movieID`. Can you confirm this is what you want?

Comment: where movieID >= 20
order by movieID desc

Comment: Post sample input data and expected output please

Answer (score 1):

You did not specify whether movieID has the IDENTITY property. But nonetheless, try this:

```
SELECT movieID, movieTitle, category FROM dbo.Movie 
WHERE movieID > 20
ORDER BY movieID DESC
```